# Text Below Image in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to add Text below my Image in Grid View. I am getting Null point Exception error.

Below is the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:background="#000080">

   <imageview android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </imageview>

   <textview android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TextView"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textColor="#000000">
   </textview>

</LinearLayout>
```

The ImageAdapter class has below code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image4



    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    public ImageAdapter(Residential residential) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View MyView = convertView;

        if (convertView == null)
        {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, 
                    parent,false);

        TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
        tv.setText("Item");

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(190, 100));
        }
        return MyView;
    }

}
```

It's throwing null exception error at below line:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, 
                    parent,false);
```

I tried with various option suggested but all giving same results

```
LayoutInflater li = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Please suggest how to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: post the stack trace. also initialize `TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);` and return `convertView`. Also use a view holder http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: what is `Residential`?

Comment: @RobinHood: Residential is the gridview xml file.

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thanks. Tried as suggested but still getting error.

Comment: @user2582509 post the stack trace pls

Comment: @user2582509 is the xml posted `grid_item`?

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks. It's done now. The problem was giving layout parameters. I removed below code and it worked. Thanks all.                   imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(190, 100));

Comment: @user2582509 oh ok lol. was wondering why my suggestion din't work i will post the comment as an answer.

Comment: @user2582509 also consider using a view holder for smooth scrolling and performance. check the link in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment's you said

```
    Residential is the gridview xml file
```

So use

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.resedential, 
                parent,false);
```

Also use convertview to initialize your views

```
TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
```

and `return convertView`.

You should also consider using a `ViewHolder`.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Use a ViewHolder

```
static class ViewHolder
{
       TextView textview;
       ImageView imageView;
}
```

In `getView`

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
    vh = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.resedential, 
                parent,false);
    vh.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text)
    vh.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    convertView.setTag(vh); 
    }
    else 
    { 
    vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }       
    vh.tv.setText("Item");   
    vh.imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    vh.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    vh.imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(190, 100));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: use a view holder give the above a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since MyView is pointing to convertView which could be null but after assigning a new view you have not updated MyView with new convertView.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View MyView = convertView;

        if (convertView == null)
        {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, 
                    parent,false);
MyView = convertView;
        TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
        tv.setText("Item");

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(190, 100));
        }
        return MyView;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried as suggested but still the same issue.

Comment: At which line are u getting NullPointException

Answer (score 0):

That's how inflate works:

```
static View inflate(Context context, int resource, ViewGroup root)
Inflate a view from an XML resource.
```

So you're passing wrong params..

so

```
convertView= mInflater.inflate(getBaseContext(),R.layout.grid_item,parent);
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the parameters but it's giving 'The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type ImageAdapter' error.

Comment: don't think that's a problem http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean). check the docs

Comment: @Raghunandan pls help me in this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986878/android-json-is-not-able-to-retrieve-any-files-from-mysql-database-it-is-empty/22987428?noredirect=1#22987428