# Android: Json is not able to retrieve any files from mysql database it is empty

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

i am new to android and i am using mysql database where i am linking php file for connection which is working fine but my code is not displaying anything it is only showing background color black instead of displaying the data from the database

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {



GridView gv;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    gv = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView_home);
    getData();
    return rootView;
}
public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/Android/App/getcu.php"); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
}
catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        gv.setFilterText("Couldnt connect to database "+ e.getMessage()); //not printing anything
}
//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
}
catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
}


try {


   String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       s = s + 
               "Name : "+json.getString("FirstName")+" "+json.getString("LastName")+"\n"+
               "Age : "+json.getInt("Age")+"\n"+
               "Mobile Using : "+json.getString("Mobile")+"\n\n";//+
               "Artist:"+json.put("Images",true ); // not printing anything 
   }

   gv.setFilterText(s); // not printing showing empty
} catch (Exception e) {



// TODO: handle exception
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString()); }

}  }
```

one more error while retrieving images from folder Android/pictures/image1 json is not printing the particular image deployed into database

```
"Artist:"+json.put("Images",true );
```

is the above statement correct to retrieve the images using json or i have to correct it

please help me to correct the above program thanks for your valuable time i am not able to understand why it is not printing anything but it is working when i extend it to  activity how to use it in fragment

Comment: Can you post the Json String "result" ?

Comment: After `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result)`, how many elements are in the JSONArray?

Comment: MANY ELEMENTS ARE THERE IN JSONaRRAY BUT IN DATABASE ON 5 FIELDS ARE THERE FIRSTNAME LASTNAME aGE MOBILE AND IMAGES @HannoBinder

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to `gv.setFilterText(s)`? This does not by itself cause the string to be displayed in the `GridView`. Is there an item *inside* the `GridView` that should receive the string?

Comment: NO I DONT KNOW ABOUT SETFILTERTEXT i used settext but it got error and changed automatically so i am asking whether it is correct or wrong what i should write there instead of setfiltertext @HannoBinder pls help me

Comment: @kAnNaN it must display from database like example "FirstName":"Sandeep","LastName":"FR","Age":"22","Mobile":"9125896365","Images":"Android/pictures/sandeep1"

Comment: pls can anyone help friends

Comment: @Raghunandan help in need

Comment: So you want the rows form the database as JsonArray right?

Comment: @kAnNaN yes i have created 5 fields inside that there are many rows i want to retrieve that one

Comment: yes u r correct @kAnNaN

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to avoid adding more comments:

1. Make sure you have the correct JSON data in your `result` string. [Logging](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) can help with tasks like that. Or maybe just use a [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) to just display the string to verify it's correct.
2. `gv.setFilterText(s);` will **not** cause any output. To display strings in the GUI you should use a [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) item that you put *inside* your layout, `GridView` in this case, and [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) on it.

Comment: how to use setText() then using GridView @Hanno Binder

Comment: Look at how `GridView` is to be [used](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). To display something in a `GridView` you'll need an implementation of a `ListAdapter`.